# ListAgg in Oracle sql (based on 2 tables)

Tags: sql, oracle

My explanation as below.

```
BRDB.EXPORT SHIPMENT (table)

 SHPMNT_REF  | SHIPMENT_TYPE
    867      | EHH
    868      | EHH
    869      | EHH

BRDB.EVENT_CODE (table)

 FILE_NO  | REMARKS   EVENT_CODE
 867      | TEST0      SIR
 867      | TEST1      SIR
 867      | TEST2      SIR
 867      | TEST3      SIR
 868      | TEST4      EEO

I want my report is showing as below

  FILE NO    |  REMARKS
     123     |  TEST0,TEST1,TEST2
     456     |  TEST3
```

I have received error when running these code "Multiple columns are returned from a subquery that is allowed only one column".

```
select min(X.SHPMNT_REF) as "House B/L #",
       listagg(case when SIR = 1 then X.REMARKS end, ',') within group (order by X.SHPMNT_REF) as "REMARKS(from SIR Event)"
FROM   (select ES.SHPMNT_REF,
               (select EE.REMARKS,
                       row_number() over (order by EE.FILE_NO)
                FROM   BRDB.EXPORT_EVENT EE
                where  EE.FILE_NO = ES.SHPMNT_REF
                and    EE.EVENT_CODE = 'SIR') as SIR
        from   BRDB.EXPORT_SHIPMENT ES)X
GROUP BY X.SHPMNT_REF
```

Comment: Your question is a mess. Please edit it so other could understand your problem. If I only read your input and expected output, I couldn't understand why `123` and `456` suddenly appear in output with no occur in input. If I read your query, I couldn't understad what is table `EXPORT_EVENT`???

Answer (score 0):

Assume your sample input is wrong by typo, this simple query should work for you

```
SELECT file_no, 
    LISTAGG(remarks, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY remarks) AS remarks
FROM brdb.event_code
WHERE event_code = 'SIR'
GROUP BY file_no
ORDER BY file_no;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has the following issues, firstly the table names in the first part EXPORT_SHIPMENT (I assume there's an underscore in there) and EVENT_CODE do not match the code snippet you provided. Also are you trying to combine the row numbers into the file no field? Very hard to determine what you are looking for.

For the original error, Oracle correlated subqueries do not support multiple columns. This is causing that error, you can return `ee.remarks` or `row_number()`, not both.

```
select EE.REMARKS,
row_number() over (order by EE.FILE_NO)
from   BRDB.EXPORT_EVENT EE
where  EE.FILE_NO = ES.SHPMNT_REF
and    EE.EVENT_CODE = 'SIR'
```

My best guess for the what you want is something like this, notice that I am joining the tables not trying a subquery.

```
select X.FILE_NO 
       ,listagg(X.REMARKS || ',') within group (order by X.SHPMNT_REF) 
       ,listagg(X.ROW_NUM) within group (order by X.SHPMNT_REF) 

FROM  
(
    select EE.FILE_NO,
           ES.SHPMNT_REF,
           EE.REMARKS,
           row_number() over (order by EE.FILE_NO) as ROW_NUM
    FROM   EVENT_CODE       EE
    JOIN   EXPORT_SHIPMENT  ES
      ON   EE.FILE_NO = ES.SHPMNT_REF
    AND    EE.EVENT_CODE = 'SIR'
) X
group by X.FILE_NO
```